# "==" operator seeems not to work for floating point numbers

Tags: c, if-statement, floating-point, comparison-operators

Can someone please explain the output here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float f = 0.1 ;
    printf ("%f\n",f ) ;
    if (f == 0.100000) {
        printf ("true ") ;
    }
    else {
        printf ("False") ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
0.100000
False
```

Comment: This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `float` number with a `double`. The number `0.100000`is considered as `double`type unless you specify with a trailing `f` that it is a `float.` Thus:

```cpp
int main(){
    float x = 0.100000;
    if (x == 0.100000)
        printf("NO");
    else if (x == 0.100000f)
        // THE CODE GOES HERE
        printf("YES");
    else
        printf("NO");
}
```

You mat refer to [single precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) and [double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) for theoritical details

Answer (score 1):

Objects of the types float and double are stored with different precisions.

You should write

```
 if (f == 0.100000f) {
```

trying to compare two floats.

Also it would be better to initialize the variable f with a constant of the type float

```
float f = 0.1f;
```

Answer (score 0):

`0.100000` is double by default, try `0.100000f`. if you need to compare with double, you need to try something described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison).